# Android kernel compilation

Tags: android, makefile, kernel

For compiling the kernel for Android below are the steps:

```
$ export ARCH=arm
$ export SUBARCH=arm
$ export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi-
$ cd omap
$ git checkout <commit_from_first_step>
$ make tuna_defconfig
$ make
```

I want to change the default configuration of kernel by editing .config file (enabling certain flags for Multimedia and V4L2). However when i try to perform "make", the .config file is overwritten by default values and kernel is compiled with these values.
I tried editing the .config file and performing "make oldconfig" but the same result.

Any way to edit .config file ?

Answer (score 0):

.config file is auto generated file, changing any flags in .config will not affect the kernel configuration. To change the kernel configuration you need to open configuration window by typing below command in your kernel folder:
**make ARCH=arm menuconfig**

PS:: if you are using ubuntu 12.04 you may get some error while executing the 'make ARCH=arm menuconfig' command, to get rid of it try (atleast it worked for me):
**sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5-dev**

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to overwrite configuration use defconfig and take configuration of tuna_defconfig , append it to defconfig . Then try to build kernel using make command.